# AFNetworking + WCF Streaming is not working as expected (all data is buffered at client)

Tags: c#, objective-c, wcf, afnetworking

so after alot of playing around, changing from RESTKit to the base AFNetworking, we still can't get streaming to work as expected.

we are streaming a file to a WCF server:

```
RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

// Build the request
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [manager.HTTPClient requestWithMethod:@"PUT" path:action parameters:nil];


// note - this method inserts all parameters to the URL. so we will construct a new URL and add the parameters
// this line is taken from AFNetworking.

    // we set the file name in the URL
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[request.URL absoluteString] stringByAppendingFormat:[action rangeOfString:@"?"].location == NSNotFound ? @"?%@" : @"&%@", AFQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding(params, manager.HTTPClient.stringEncoding)]];
    [request setURL:url];

// all requests will have a stream type (as we are posting raw data)
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/octet-stream"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


// we are overriding any body that the request added - because we want the whole rawData to be sent as a body. Data streaming.
[request setHTTPBodyStream:dataStream];



// Set the upload timeout
[request setTimeoutInterval:999999];

AFHTTPRequestOperation* httpOp =[manager.HTTPClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"sucesS");

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Failure");

}];

[httpOp setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

    NSLog(@"uploading..");

}];

[manager.HTTPClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:httpOp];
```

i see that immediately the delegate is called and the bytes written are constantly raising.
but the server doesn't receive **ANYTHING** 
after the success is called, **only then**, the server starts handling the file.

our server side web config:

```
  <endpoint address="Upload" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webUploadHttpBindingConfig" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="IREST" />


 ...

 <binding name="webUploadHttpBindingConfig" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                </security>
            </binding>
```

in the server code we creates the file and just stream it to disk.

i'm pulling my hairs out, what's missing here?

thanks.

Comment: You should have updated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452778/correct-way-to-define-timeouts-in-afnetworking-restkit-for-download-uploading rather than create an effective duplicate question. Did you check the server buffering and logs? What does `maxBufferSize` do?

Comment: @Wain - the other one talks about timeout. i'll delete that question.
maxBufferSize="2147483647

there are no logs at server, the IIS doesn't even receive the request until buffering in the IPAD is done.

Comment: Have you used Charles to see what is sent and when?

Comment: @Wain - i couldnt  get it running. Our server doesnt have outgoing internet connection and i dont have much time to spend to start installing a new one. I think though ive added everything we have, from client code to server code and web config..